# c++ string: is there good way to replace a char inside a string

Tags: c++, string, stl

I want to replace all the occurances of ' in a string to ^, but i saw string.replace is not the right function for me, do I need to write my own? It's boring.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`std::replace`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/replace) from `<algorithm>` instead of using `string::replace` from `<string>`

Sample code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   std::string s = "I am a string";
   std::replace(s.begin(),s.end(),' ',',');
   std::cout<< s;

}
```

Output : `I,am,a,string`

Comment: +1 for a straight-forward solution that makes my custom built STD::replace functions a waste.